# Does django perform an implicit update of related models?

Tags: django, orm

I am trying to understand how the following code works under the hood:

```
# models.py

class M1(models.Model):
    m2 = models.ForeignKey('M2', related_name='m1s', null=True, blank=True)

class M2(models.Model):
    m1 = models.ForeignKey('M1', related_name='m2_set', null=True, blank=True)
```

```
# elsewhere

m2 = M2()

m1 = M1()
m1.m2 = m2

m1.save() # no error! according to the docs, this shouldn't be allowed

m1_persisted = M1.objects.get(id=m1.id)
print(m1_persisted.m2 == None) # True, as expected since m2 was never saved

m2.m1 = m1
m2.save() # this is fine, m1 was previously saved

m1_persisted = M1.objects.get(id=m1.id)
print(m1_persisted.m2.id) # prints m2's id! why does calling m2.save() update m1?
```

According to the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/#:%7E:text=Note,-that%20you%20must) it looks like I should get an error of the form `ValueError: save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object` when first calling `m1.save()`, but I don't. Is this expected behavior or is there something else going on here (potentially in an overridden save method)

I tried digging around in the django source for `.save()` [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/_modules/django/db/models/base/#Model.save) but was unable to figure out what its doing.

Comment: Why do you think that should not be allowed?

Comment: When calling `m1.save()` most likely you don't get any error because `m1` must save `m2.id` which is `null` at that time (`m2` hasn't been saved yet therefore it's `id` is `null`/`None`), and you explicitly allowed `null` values in your `ForeignKey`.

Comment: I strongly encourage you to set `django.db` logger level to `DEBUG` (and logging handler level also to `DEBUG`) so you will see which exactly database queries django sends to your database in which order. This way you will see what exactly happens.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I think it shouldn't be allowed due to the linked docs. The only difference is setting the unsaved object in the constructor vs the assignment operator. (search: "save() prohibited" to see what I'm talking about)

Comment: @Art I have enabled the db `DEBUG` logging and it is indeed updating m1 when calling `m2.save()`. What I don't know for sure is whether this is normal django behavior or whether some explicit logic is doing this in the overridden `M2.save()` method. Its complex and difficult to dig through.